# How to add nested y-axis labels in a bar chart plotted via ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I want to insert two strip of texts above and below the y-intercept = 0 line stating "better" and "worse". I tried facet_wrap and panel.spacing to eliminate the space. But, it is leaving a space between the above bars and below bars. It messes with my y-axis scale as well. i.e., the position = "dodge" gets wiped off for certain bars and for certain bars I see the position dodged.

Can someone help me, please? TIA

Comment: Sounds like a job for `annotate("text", ...)`

Comment: Please show us the plot and the expected output. It's hard to help when you use text only

Comment: Well, I figured out. `textGrob and grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(...))` does the job. Thanks.